# knockout decrease DOM manipulation

Tags: knockout.js

I was wondering is there a way to decrease the Dom manipulation of knockoutjs - i have a large observable array and i see that in the foreach it takes allot of time.

After investigating the code and debug it abit i see that knockout put every element in the dom instead of putting all the elements at one.

Is there a quick way to let knockout create a long string of all the child nodes in the foreach statement and then write that string to the DOM once?

my code:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray([]);     
function generateModel(data) {
            var mapped = $.map(data, function (d) { return new item(d); });
            self.items(mapped);
        }

<!--ko foreach:{data:items}-->
some template in here
<!--/ko-->
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach` binding is not terribly efficient at rendering large arrays. It's designed to efficiently handle dynamic arrays (that may be modified in small ways).

There are a few solutions that might help you:

1. Use a string-based template. An [example using Underscore is in the Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_7_using_the_underscorejs_template_engine).
2. Use a custom binding that generates specific HTML content and adds it to the DOM. An example of this technique is my [`table` binding](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-table).
3. Use a faster `foreach`-style binding like my [`repeat` binding](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat).

Comment: Hi. thanks for the answer. I was looking for a way save a giant string  and then add him only once to the dom. In my web site i saw that knockout struggle with a large array - I reduce that array by paging from the server but you still see sometime the rendering takes long time. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Is there a way in knockout to use several template engines?

Comment: I've updated the Underscore example to use the `templateEngine` option, which supports this: http://jsfiddle.net/6pStz/340/

Answer (score 2):

if you want you can find a couple of good hints here:
http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Even better, you can find here an interesting implementation of custom object called pauseableObservableArray (great name:) from a giant developer: rpniemeyer)  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fYnjG/

Beside this, for a first simple approach, did you tried to remove from DOM the element with a an `if` binding?

eg.
html:

```
<!-- ko ifnot: isWorking -->
<div data-bind="foreach: blogs">
    <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
</div>

<!-- /ko -->
```

viewmodel:

```
function BlogViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.blogs = ko.observableArray([{id:'qwe'}]);

    self.isWorking= ko.observable(false);


    self.populateBlogs = function () {
        self.isWorking(true);

        var tmp =  self.blogs();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            tmp.push({id:i});
        }


        self.blogs(tmp);
        self.isWorking(false);
    }


}
```

[UPDATE]
Probably, if you need to improve more the rendering timing, you need to implement something similar to what implemented in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fYnjG/) I suggested, or implement a custom binding handler to do everything "by hand".
For example, something similar to:

html:

```
<div data-bind="quickForEach: blogs"></div>
```

viemodel:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.quickForEach = {

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var blogs = valueAccessor()();
        var innerText='';
        for (var i = 0; i < blogs.length; i++) {
            //very dirty code!In production, concatenate strings in a smarter way
            innerText += blogs[i].id;
        }
        $(element).text(innerText);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'll take a look at what Michael Best suggested and do the string based template like you suggested in the update. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your tip related to ifnot approach - that increased rendering two times.

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is a way using throttle extenders: see docs at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html

Comment: I don't want to delay the foreach statement ( which is what throttle does as far as i understand) - I dont want knockout to push 200 elements that i have in the observableArray with 200 append to the dom but just in one append.

Comment: and how many items are causing you problem? do you really need to render all items on this page, why not do some sort of virtual rendering?